# Magento 1.9 API v2 Payment Additional Information

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, payment, soap-api-v2, additional-information

I'm trying to extend the API response of Magento [SalesOrderInfo](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html) - more specifically, I'm trying to get back the `paymnent additional_information`

In my module, in `etc/wsdl.xml` I added

```
        <complexType name="salesOrderPaymentEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="last_trans_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

And it works like a charm, it returns the value of `last_trans_id` from the `sales_flat_order_payment` table.

I'm now trying to get the `paymnent additional_information` so I added `<element name="additional_information" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />` and my code now looks like this

```
        <complexType name="salesOrderPaymentEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="last_trans_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="additional_information" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

but the `additional_information` is not returning anything because it's an array (when I logged it, it returns `Array`)

I hate asking such a basic question but I've spent hours looking for how to get an array, I looked at how Magento returns the `product_options` that's also an array but they also declare it as a string.

How can I get the `additional_information` of payment in my API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the answer here in case someone else bumps in to the same issue.

Magento order object already returns the `additional_information` as an array, so we just needed to add a typens

`<element name="additional_information" type="typens:salesOrderPaymentAdditionalInformationEntity" minOccurs="0" />`

and then parse out the line items - I did it for 3 different payment methods (Auth.net, PayPal and Amazon)

```
        <complexType name="salesOrderPaymentAdditionalInformationEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="response_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="response_subcode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="response_reason_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="response_reason_text" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="approval_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="auth_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="avs_result_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="transaction_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="reference_transaction_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="invoice_number" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="method" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="transaction_type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="customer_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="md5_hash" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="card_code_response_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="cavv_response_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="acc_number" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="card_type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="split_tender_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="requested_amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="balance_on_card" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="profile_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="payment_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="is_fraud" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_express_checkout_shipping_method" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_payer_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_payer_email" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_payer_status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_address_status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_correlation_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_express_checkout_payer_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_express_checkout_token" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_protection_eligibility" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_payment_status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="paypal_pending_reason" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="order_reference" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
```